# Passing a Four-Dimensional Array to a Chart SeriesCollection using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I want to know how to pass a single dimension of a four-dimensional array to an XY Scatter Chart using VBA.

> [I know that I could do it by laboriously typing out separate arrays for everything, but I was hoping to make my code more compact. The compactness is particularly useful for populating the array, which I have not included below as I have that done already. I also know that if I were using 2D arrays, then I could use `Application.Index`, but my understanding is that that will not work for a three dimensional array or four dimensional array - if I'm wrong about that, then please let me know. I have looked at numerous queries on several websites, and I can only find answers about 2D arrays using `Application.Index` - if there is a page I've missed, then please let me know.]

I have an array variable that I have populated:

```
Dim arrData() As Single
arrData(1 To 2, 1 To 4, 1 To 3, 1 To 56)
```

`arrData` contains `Single`-type data for variables 1 to 56, within a 2x4x3 layout, so 1,344 data points.

I have a chart:

```
Dim bIOpt As Byte
Dim bPOpt As Byte

For bIOpt = 1 To 4
For bPOpt = 1 To 4

Worksheets("Data").Activate
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Select
Charts.Add
With ActiveChart
   .Type = xlXYScatter
   .ChartTitle.Delete
   With .SeriesCollection(1)
      .XValues = ?
      .Values = ?
   End With
   .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   With .SeriesCollection(2)
      .XValues = ?
      .Values = ?
   End With
   .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   With .SeriesCollection(3)
      .XValues = ?
      .Values = ?
   End With
End With

Next bPOpt
Next bIOpt
```

I want each `SeriesCollection` to contain 56 points from `arrData`: the `XValues` will come from the `bPOpt` version of `arrData(2, bPOpt, n, )`; the (Y) `Values` will come from the `bIOpt` version of `arrData(1, bIOpt, n, )`.

I do not know how to write the "`.XValues = ?`" and "`.Values = ?`" lines so as to achieve my aim.

Thank you for your help.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could use whatever looping algorithm you want to generate 1-D arrays for XValues and YValues, then pass these arrays to the chart series:

```
Dim XVals(1 to 56) As Double, YVals(1 to 56) As Double

' loop to populate XVals, YVals from arrData
' blah blah
' end of loop

With .SeriesCollection(1)
    .Values = YVals
    .XValues = XVals
End With
```

Note that there's no advantage in VBA to using Singles in place of Doubles, or Ints in place of Longs.

Note also that Excel's charts are much more reliable when working with data from worksheet cells than with arrays. If you experience problems, you might first dump XVals and YVals into a couple columns, then use this data range as the chart series data.

Comment: Thanks Jon - I did end up re-writing it to use fewer than four dimensions (I used a series of 2D arrays, rather than the 1D arrays you suggest). It made my code higher up more complicated, is all. So I had wondered whether it was even possible to pass a 4D array to the chart.

I thought Single was 32-bit and Double was 64-bit? Also, I find that dumping the data to charts is slower than using an array, so I prefer not to.

Comment: You can't pass a 4D array into a worksheet either, so I don't know why it would be possible to pass it into a chart. A chart has simple data requirements.

Comment: I think Singles are 16-bit and Doubles 32-bit. What matters is that VBA does its calculations in Double, so any Singles passed into a calc are converted to Double, and if necessary the result is converted back to Single. Any overflow occurs after the calc, in the second conversion. Using Singles doesn't buy anything, since it costs you two conversions and a possible overflow error. Same logic applies to Integers and Longs.

Comment: You can place dimensions from the 4D array into a worksheet easily: For lRow 1 to 56 Cells(lRow,1) = arrData(1, 1, 1, lRow). That doesn't work when trying to define XValues. That's good to know about Singles and Doubles though, I knew about the stupid conversions with Integers and Longs but not Single and Doubles.

Comment: It could take a while to populate a range one cell at a time. Dump the values into a 2D array, then do Range("A1").Resize(nRows, nCols).Value = arrData2D